# Extract columns from list of tables in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have a list of tables, where each table is a list of lists.  I'd like to extract the columns from each table to get a lists of columns.  An example should clarify:

```
input=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]]
output=[[[1,4],[7,10],[13,16]],[[2,5],[8,11],[14,17]],[[3,6],[9,12],[15,18]]]
```

I know I can probably use several for loops, but it feels like there should be a nice one liner to do this.

I intend to assign the results to variables:

```
a,b,_=output
```

With a single table, I can extract the columns with:

```
>>>input=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>>list(zip(*input))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

or for assignment:

```
>>>a,b,_=zip(*input)
>>>a
(1, 4)
>>>b
(2, 5)
```

But for a list of tables, I haven't been able to do it.  Here are some of the things I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
>>>list(zip(*zip(*input)))
[([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]), ([7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]), ([13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18])]
>>>[list(zip(*inp)) for inp in input]
[[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)], [(7, 10), (8, 11), (9, 12)], [(13, 16), (14, 17), (15, 18)]]
>>>[[x,y,z] for x,y,z in [zip(*inp) for inp in input]]
#same as above
>>> [[x,y] for inp in input for x,y in zip(*inp)]
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7, 10], [8, 11], [9, 12], [13, 16], [14, 17], [15, 18]]
```

And nested/unpacked assignment didn't work for me either:

```
>>>[[a,b,_]]=[zip(*inp) for inp in input]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
>>>[*a,*b,*_]=[[x,y] for x,y in [zip(*inp) for inp in input]]
SyntaxError: two starred expressions in assignment
```

Is there a one-liner to do what I'm trying to do?

Edit: Note that while the example is specifically 3 tables with 2 rows and 3 columns each, my actual use case has unknown numbers of tables and rows.

I ended up using this line in my code:

```
list(zip(*[zip(*inp) for inp in input]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got close with that last attempt.  You need one more, well-chosen nesting level.  EDIT: I added the final `zip` step to get the desired ordering.  I also used that "star" notation to help show how to extend the concept.

```
given = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
         [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],
         [[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]]

f1 = [[[a, b] for a, b in zip(list1, list2)] for list1, list2 in given]
print(f1)
f2 = list(zip(*f1))
print(f2)
```

Output (edited for readability)

```
[[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]], 
 [[7, 10], [8, 11], [9, 12]], 
 [[13, 16], [14, 17], [15, 18]]]

[([1, 4], [7, 10], [13, 16]),
 ([2, 5], [8, 11], [14, 17]),
 ([3, 6], [9, 12], [15, 18])]
```

The second one has tuples instead of lists at the middle level; is that okay?  If not, can you fix it?  (left as an exercise for the student ... )

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for columns of any length?

Comment: It already does work for the third dimension.
If you want it to work for the first two, simply trade in the pair of variables, replacing with "star" expansion, such as `*var`.  Is that enough to make it clear?

Comment: The *var makes sense.  Looking at this more though, it appears it does something slightly different than what I'm looking for.  Applying this to my original input I get: [[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]], [[7, 10], [8, 11], [9, 12]], [[13, 16], [14, 17], [15, 18]]]

Comment: (1) As best I can see, the output you posted is identical to the desired output.  (2) If you need to ask another question, please post it separately.  Comments are not a good place to solve coding difficulties.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking at, but my desired output is the one with [7,10] as the second pair.

Comment: Ah ... got it.  You and I got the same results with this code -- but it's not what you want.  I thought that you were saying you got results different from mine.